# extend background outside of grid foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Is there a way to extend a backround to the left or right out of a grid? for example if i wanted to do a 100% background with a grid in place i would do something like:

```
<div class="100%BACKGROUND">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="large-12 columns>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which works perfectly but what if i wanted  to extend a background color outside of the grid to the side of the page and by this i mean for example

```
<div class="row>

     <div class="large-8 columns">

     </div>

     <div class="BACKGROUNDSTART"> <-- background start

     <div class="large-4 columns">

     </div>

 </div>

 </div> <-- background end
```

Now this doesn't work obviously but this is the kind of thing i am trying to achieve heres a mockup of how it would look.

[image: Grid]

Comment: You mean like this? - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bALoz

Comment: This works but i plan to have content in this area and using the ::after pseudo-element covers up any content in that area (text for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved with a pseufo-element as follows:

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/joBpE)

Basic **HTML** structure

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="level"></div>
  <div class="level">
    <div class="split"></div>
    <div class="split purple"></div> /* div to be extended */
  </div>
  <div class="level"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container {
  width:960px;
  margin: 0  auto;

}
.level {
  height:100px;
  background: #bada55;
  clear:both;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.split {
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}

.purple {
  position: relative;
  background: #663399;
  opacity:0.5; /* just for visibility of effect */
}


.purple:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: #663399;  /* Match the background */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 9999px;   /* some huge width */
} 

.purple:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Adding `margin: 0 -2000px` (or any big number) might be also useful.